# Certain BigDecimal numbers in Java when divided causes the ArithmeticException to be thrown

Tags: java, bigdecimal, arithmeticexception

The following approach to divide two `BegDecimal` numbers works fine.

```
BigDecimal a=new BigDecimal(5);
BigDecimal b=new BigDecimal(2);
System.out.println(a.divide(b));
```

Output : `2.5`

---

The following same approach however fails with the `java.lang.ArithmeticException`

```
BigDecimal c=new BigDecimal(361);
BigDecimal d=new BigDecimal(6);
System.out.println(c.divide(d));
```

The following is the complete exception stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException:
Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
    at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:1603)
    at currenttime.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Java Result: 1
```

What's the solution?

Comment: You need to set a rounding mode. Otherwise it defaults to "exact".

Comment: More info: http://jaydeepm.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/bigdecimal-and-non-terminating-decimal-expansion-error/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one argument [`BigDecimal.Divide`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) throws an `ArithmeticException` if the quotient is a non-terminating decimal (361/6 is 60.1666666...):

> Throws:
>   **ArithmeticException** - if the exact quotient does not have a
>   terminating decimal expansion

To avoid this use the [`overload`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29) with a second [`RoundingMode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) parameter.

I.e., you tell BigDecimal exactly what you expect from the division result.

Answer (score 2):

This is as expected by the Java spec. You have not provided any scale, and since 361/6 = 60.1(6) it should throw that exception. If you want some rounding you should provide a scale, meaning how much digits after the decimal point to return, or you might want devideAndReminder for dividing with reminder.

Answer (score 2):

You could, say round to 5 decimal places:

```
BigDecimal c=new BigDecimal(361);
BigDecimal d=new BigDecimal(6);
System.out.println(c.divide(d, 5, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN));
```